# Java SWT - Adding buttons to shell

Tags: java, swt

I'm trying to create a simple window with a push button using the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{       
    Display display=new Display();
    Shell shell=new Shell();

    shell.open();
    shell.setText("Hi there!");
    shell.setSize(500,500);

    Button pushButton = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
    pushButton.setText("Im a Push Button");
    //pushButton.pack();

    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }

    shell.dispose();
}
```

When commenting out the "pushButton.pack()" line, the button will not appear on the window.
Is it really necessary to call the pack() method for every button I want to add?
What if I have 10 buttons?

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    new Button(shell, SWT.RADIO).setText("option "+(i+1));
}
```

How will it then work?

Plus,
is there a good SWT tutorial for beginners online?
Can you recommend a book that can guide me through SWT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program should look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{       
    Display display=new Display();
    Shell shell=new Shell();

    // Set a layout
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
    shell.setText("Hi there!");

    Button pushButton = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
    pushButton.setText("Im a Push Button");

    // Move the shell stuff to the end
    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
    shell.setSize(500,500);

    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
}
```

That way, you only call `pack()` once on the `Shell`.

---

These are definitely must-reads for SWT beginners:

- [Understanding Layouts in SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Understanding-Layouts/index.html)
- [SWT turorial by Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/SWT/article.html)

Comment: Thank you Baz.
But I now have a 500x500 size button... 
BTW, does it matter when do I call the shell.open() method?

Comment: @so.very.tired The button is this size, because of the `FillLayout` and the `setSize(500, 500)` call. You can call `shell.open()` anywhere you want, but `shell.pack()` and the `shell.setSize()` should be called after you added all you initial controls.